# XCODE HELP - Main Method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, printing, xcode4, printf

I am a newbie programming Objective C in Xcode. Can someone explain to me why the following prints nothing upon pressing build:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello");
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```

Comment: why would you want to work within the main method? that's asking for trouble...

Comment: I'm not developing anything, I'm just getting to grips with xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If you build the program, then *run* it, you will be able to read your "Hello" message in the Xcode Console (cmd-shift-r to open it, or check in the Run menu).

Otherwise, you will read a message explaining what went wrong.